# AVAudioPlayer totally remove from App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, audio, avfoundation

facing a new problem on my new app :

I have a nav based app, in a UIViewController i have a AVAudioPlayer instance, when the view disappear i call :

```
 [myAVAudiPlayer stop];
```

it stops, everything is ok, when i get back to springboard i launch my music and when i get back to my app the music stops.

I think that is because my AVAudioPlayer is still on,

how do i do to completely remove this AVAudioPlayer ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because you haven't configured the [Audio Session](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875). As you've found, the default AudioSession mostly does the right things. However, you want to mix with other apps' audio.

You can change set this option using:

```
[AVAudioSession sharedInstance].category = AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers;
```

Apple advises you configure the AudioSession for any non-trivial app than uses audio.  There are other configuration options concerning the handling of interruptions and changes or audio routing that you ought to also set.

Comment: Do i do not need my AVAudioPlayer instance anymore ? I have to an AVAUdoSession shared instance that's it ?

Comment: No. You still require the AVAudioPlayer.